# Should new lawn mower buyers purchase an electric lawn mower instead of a gas-powered lawn mower?

Tags: lawn, lawn-mower

It seems like the world is transitioning to electric. Cars used to have carburetors. Then fuel injectors came along. People began buying cars with fuel injectors because they're superior. Now electric cars are replacing gas-powered vehicles. Are electric lawnmowers the future? As a person in the market for a new lawnmower, is it better to buy electric lawnmowers instead of a gas-powered lawnmower? ("better" meaning in areas like energy consumption, reliability, and durability)

Property size: 8221 sqft 
Building square footage: 1604 
I'm currently using the 22" Craftsman 700 Series self-propelled lawnmower. A new mower that substitutes this one will do.

Comment: ...how much lawn? Purely manual mowers make much sense at a certain scale. Herds of sheep or growing hay make sense at a certain scale.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I have an average single home with a lawn size approx 5500 sqft.  I currently use Craftsman 700 Series front-wheel self-propelled lawnmower.  I've had it for more than 10 years, but it is not working anymore. I'm just trying to figure out if an electric mower is the norm for home owners now. ty :-)

Comment: I use an electric mower for my 1/3 acre lot (probably ~7,000 feet of lawn. I've been able to get two complete mowings at 3" height from one battery charge. I only have and need one battery at the moment. The mower is two+ years old and I love not having to change oil, occasionally change a sparkplug, and add gas to it every week. It's also a little but not much quieter than a gas mower. The brand is an ECO, and it's a mulching mower.

Comment: Multiple sources claim that a reel mower (manual push-type) is suitable for lawns less than 6000 square feet. (Some claim up to 10,000 sq ft) but that would depend on whether you would be open to that idea. It's better for the grass, and energy consumption, and is quite reliable and durable if you keep it somewhere dry and sharpen when needed (which varies by  models - shop well.)

Comment: I used a reel mower for the more than 22 years I lived in cities, only retiring it for the electric when I got too old to mow regularly. Although I loved it - and got a decent workout every time I mowed, there are some drawbacks: 1) It's a pain to mow if you have trees that drop sticks regularly (pin oak, willows, and basswoods in particular), 2) It's difficult to get a good cut if you mow higher than 2.5 inches 3) It can be difficult to mow if the grass is too wet due to dewfall or rain - the mower tends to glide over the blades. This can also be a function of high grass and dew together.

Comment: Buy a gas mower for now, you'll be able to buy gas until it breaks. Electric mowers will cost a lot more and have expensive consumables (batteries). The battery has to sit there all winter, which isn't great for the battery. You'll probably only get about half the charge after the 3rd summer, and making it 5 years would be impressive. So factor a replacement battery or two into the total 10-year cost when comparing.